# Java convert ArrayList to string and back to ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, string, list, arraylist

I wanted to save an ArrayList to SharedPreferences so I need to turn it into a string and back, this is what I am doing:

```
// Save to shared preferences
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("myAppsArr", myAppsArr.toString());
editor.commit();
```

I can retrieve it with `String arrayString = sharedPref.getString("yourKey", null);` but I don't know how to convert arrayString back into an ArrayList. How can it be done?

---

My array looks something like:

```
[item1,item2,item3]
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have 2 choices :

1. Manually parse the string and recreate the arraylist. This would be pretty tedious.
2. Use a JSON library like Google's [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library to store and retrieve objects as JSON strings. This is a lightweight library, well regarded and popular. It would be an ideal solution in your case with minimal work required. e.g.,

   ```
   // How to store JSON string
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   // This can be any object. Does not have to be an arraylist.
   String json = gson.toJson(myAppsArr);

   // How to retrieve your Java object back from the string
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   DataObject obj = gson.fromJson(arrayString, ArrayList.class);
   ```

Comment: I changed the array elements to strings, I'm sure it must be a lot easier now.

Comment: It doesn't matter. With Gson, you can convert any java object to a string and then convert it back. So even if you have an arraylist of custom objects, there's no problem.

Comment: Does it work for `ArrayList<SomeCustomObject>`  with `gson.fromJson(arrayString, ArrayList.class)`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
ArrayList<String> array = Arrays.asList(arrayString.split(","))
```

This will work if comma is used as separator and none of the items have it.

Answer (score 2):

The page http://mjiayou.com/2015/07/22/exception-gson-internal-cannot-be-cast-to/ contains the following:

```
Type     type  = new TypeToken<List<T>>(){}.getType();
List<T>  list  = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type)
```

perhaps it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
      //arraylist convert into String using Gson 
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      String data = gson.toJson(myArrayList);
      Log.e(TAG, "json:" + gson);

      //String to ArrayList

      Gson gson = new Gson();
      arrayList=gson.fromJson(data, new TypeToken<List<Friends>>()
      {}.getType());
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using:

```
ArrayList<String> appList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(appsString.split("\\s*,\\s*")));
```

This doesn't work for all array types though. This option differs from:

```
ArrayList<String> array = Arrays.asList(arrayString.split(","));
```

on that the second option creates an inmutable array.

Answer (score 0):

> Update to  Dhruv Gairola's answer for **Kotlin**

```
val gson = Gson();
val jsonString = gson.toJson(arrayList)
```