# Adding an item to arralist which is already saved in shared preferences in android

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I am having an array list which is already stored in shared preferences.I want to add another item in array list.
Whenever i am trying to add an item in array list it is removing all the previous data stored in arraylist

How can i add item without removing the previous data in shared preferences

```
ArrayList<String> cartArrayListID,cartArrayListName,cartArrayListPrice,cartArrayListImage;
    String cartID,cartName,cartPrice,cartImage;
cartArrayListID=new ArrayList<>();
        cartArrayListName=new ArrayList<>();
        cartArrayListPrice=new ArrayList<>();
        cartArrayListImage=new ArrayList<>();
cartArrayListID.add(cartID);
                cartArrayListName.add(cartName);
                cartArrayListPrice.add(cartPrice);
                cartArrayListImage.add(cartImage);
SharedPreferences sprefCart=getSharedPreferences("CARTINFO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editorCart=sprefCart.edit();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String id_=gson.toJson(cartArrayListID);
                String name_=gson.toJson(cartArrayListName);
                String price_=gson.toJson(cartArrayListPrice);
                String image_=gson.toJson(cartArrayListImage);
                editorCart.putString("ID", id_);
                editorCart.putString("NAME", name_);
                editorCart.putString("PRICE", price_);
                editorCart.putString("IMAGE", image_);
                editorCart.apply();
                Toast.makeText(ProductActivity.this, "Added to cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: post your code....

Comment: you have to post your code in order to we can help you, I think you don't retrieve anything from SharedPreferences so it creates a new list everytime you add an item.

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat the data is being retrieved but whenever i am adding another data to arraylist and save it to shared preferences,the previous data is removed i.e it is not adding the data to existing arraylist but replacing it with the previous data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I see in your code, you create a whole new ArrayLists `cartArrayListID`, `cartArrayListName` , ..etc everytime, and then you put the new  value into it, after that you save it in SharedPreferences which in turn will replace the old one saved in it with your new one, so you have to:

1. get the corresponding ArrayList from Shared preferences at first.(for ex. `cartArrayListName`)
2. save it in a new array called `cartArrayListID`.
3. put the new values in this new array.
4. save it back in SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get an `ArrayList` from `SharedPreferences`.

You can get a `Set` using [getStringSet](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)). Notice that the `jdoc` states that

> Note that you must not modify the set instance returned by this call.

so do something like:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet(yourPrefDataCollection);
mySet.add("some string");


sp.edit().putStringSet("your set key", mySet).commit();
```

Comment: i am saving the arraylist in shared preferences with the help of Gson class and toJson method

Comment: add the code when you are adding and saving. Also i suggest you to use my approach..if you don't need order it is more efficient

Comment: The code i have mentioned above it for adding and saving.It is working fine but the problem is that data is always saves at index 0 of array list.I mean whenever i am adding data to arraylist and save it to shared preferences the previous data is replaced by new one

Answer (score 0):

Use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to get ArrayList from the String.
Add some items.
Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14309619/3226984) example to save ArrayList to String, so you can store to SharedPreferences.

---

If your ArrayList has some special type (not String), use this construction:

```
ArrayList<Foo> list = new Gson().fromJson(
        gsonString, new TypeToken<List<Foo>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: Yeah @Vlamdimir i am getting saving and getting arraylist from GSON and it is working fine also.But when ever i am adding another data it is replacing with the previous data item i.e data is always saving at index 0 of array list

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is by storing your array as a String in JSON format. You have to create a simple POJO to store your array and the rest is simple. See example below;

```
public void saveArray(List<String> yourArray) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("YOUR_ARRAY_KEY", new Gson().toJson(new ArrayListHolder(yourArray)));
        editor.apply();
    }

public List<String> getArray() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String arrayJson = sharedPreferences.getString("YOUR_ARRAY_KEY", null);
    if (arrayJson != null) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(arrayJson, ArrayListHolder.class).getYourArray();
    }
    return null;
}

private class ArrayListHolder {
    private List<String> yourArray;

    public ArrayListHolder(List<String> yourArray) {
        this.yourArray = yourArray;
    }

    public List<String> getYourArray() {
        return yourArray;
    }

    public void setYourArray(List<String> yourArray) {
        this.yourArray = yourArray;
    }
}
```